# Error when install ioncube on wampserver

Tags: php, wampserver

I download ioncube_loader from [ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php) and extract have a file ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll And I add on `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll`
When using, I add on php.ini in wampserver:

```
zend_extension_ts = "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll"
```

But when run code using ioncube is error:

```
Site error: the file C:\wamp\www\test.php requires the ionCube PHP Loader ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the ionCube Loader Wizard to assist with installation.
```

How to fix it

Answer (score 2):

1. PHP 5.3 php.ini no more support `zend_extension_ts` please use `zend_extension`
2. please make sure your WAMP is 32-bits, ionCube Loader only support 32-bits (For Windows), please reinstall your WAMP to 32bits.

http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php

Windows VC6 (x86)

Windows VC6 (Non-TS) (x86)

Windows VC9 (x86)

Windows VC9 (Non-TS) (x86)

All the listing is **x86** ONLY

Comment: How do I know if I should download either TS or non-TS?

Comment: When you install wrong version, ioncube loader.php will let you know. So have a well guess

Answer (score 0):

in php.ini 
I copied the library into /php/ext/ folder, and I use :

> zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll"

Answer (score 0):

Wampserver 32bit was vc6 upto and including wampserver 2.1 
Wampserver2.2 32bit changed to vc9 since php 5.3.6 is only released as vc9
Wampserver **64bit** has always been **vc9**

Answer (score 0):

Copy the "ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll" in the url : `C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/bin/ioncube/`
 and mention the path in the php.ini (path : `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini`) file as below and it should be the top of any other zend extensions.

```
zend_extension="C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/bin/ioncube/ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll"
```

Hope this will help.